# To update using set SET SERVEROUTPUT command

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written script to update using

```
    SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
    DECLARE
    bugNumber NUMBER:=1234;
    bugErrorCode NUMBER;
    bugErrorMessage VARCHAR2(10000); 
    bugProductID NUMBER;
    BEGIN
```

and continued with it, but when I run it is throwing error as below so before beginning do I need to set any environment or how, as I am new to sql

```
./Updatebug.sh: line 1: SET: command not found
./Updatebug.sh: line 2: DECLARE: command not found
./Updatebug.sh: line 3: bugNumber: command not found
./Updatebug.sh: line 4: bugErrorCode: command not found
./Updatebug.sh: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./Updatebug.sh: line 5: `bugErrorMessage VARCHAR2(10000); '
```

Please help to resolve

Comment: Wow.  So much wrong here.  By invoking that script using your shell interpreter, its contents are being executed as shell commands and not run against your RDBMS—read up on [Executing SQL Statements from a Text File](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/mysql-batch-commands.html) if you want to have MySQL execute those commands instead.  However, your SQL is complete gibberish and won't work—I'm not even sure what it is that you're *trying* to do!  Please elaborate, or go back and read a beginner's tutorial on SQL.

Comment: Are you using oracle or mysql? Your code is pl/sql.